# How can I get a few variables from a single KQL query?

Tags: kql

I have a query from which I want to get a few variables: `street, house, locality, region, countryName`

```
let orderDate = datetime('2022-02-10');
let orderId = '0A524A2F83CCB1A311EC827458D6C4F6';
raw_events
| where timestamp between (orderDate .. 1d)
| where messageType == 'OrderPlacedEvent'
| extend messageAsJSON=parse_json(message)
| where messageAsJSON.orderId == orderId
| extend street = messageAsJSON.address.street
| extend house = messageAsJSON.address.house
| extend locality = messageAsJSON.address.locality
| extend region = messageAsJSON.address.region
| extend countryName = messageAsJSON.address.countryName
```

Is there a better way of achieving that other than executing the same query a few times:

```
let orderDate = datetime('2022-02-10');
let orderId = '0A524A2F83CCB1A311EC827458D6C4F6';
let street = raw_events
| where timestamp between (orderDate .. 1d)
| where messageType == 'OrderPlacedEvent'
| extend messageAsJSON=parse_json(message)
| where messageAsJSON.orderId == orderId
| project street = messageAsJSON.address.street;
let house = raw_events
| where timestamp between (orderDate .. 1d)
| where messageType == 'OrderPlacedEvent'
| extend messageAsJSON=parse_json(message)
| where messageAsJSON.orderId == orderId
| project street = messageAsJSON.address.house;
print toscalar(street),toscalar(house);
```

**UPDATE**

Made it the following way

```
let addres2look4 = raw_events
| where timestamp between (orderDate .. 1d)
| where messageType == mType
| where message.orderId == orderId
| project address = message.address
| evaluate bag_unpack(address);
let countryName = toscalar(addres2look4 | project countryName);
let region = toscalar(addres2look4 | project region);
let locality = toscalar(addres2look4 | project locality);
let street = toscalar(addres2look4 | project street);
let house = toscalar(addres2look4 | project house);
```

Comment: Seems like an opportunity for a feature request - support multiple assignment for a single `let` statement

Answer (score 1):

Here's an efficient way to achieve this (note the use of the [`materialize()` function)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/materializefunction):

```
let addres2look4 = materialize(
    raw_events
    | where timestamp between (orderDate .. 1d)
    | where messageType == mType
    | where message.orderId == orderId
    | project address = message.address
    | evaluate bag_unpack(address));
let countryName = toscalar(addres2look4 | project countryName);
let region = toscalar(addres2look4 | project region);
let locality = toscalar(addres2look4 | project locality);
let street = toscalar(addres2look4 | project street);
let house = toscalar(addres2look4 | project house);
```

The `materialize()` function caches the subquery's result during the time of query execution, so that the subsequent `let` statements will be much faster.